# Adding another User ID if that wasn't present in a string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using this function;

```
function add_profile_visitor($add_uid,$to_uid,$visitors_list)
{
    global $db;
        $list = trim($visitors_list);
        $list_users = explode(",",$list);

        if (in_array($add_uid,$list_users))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strpos($list_users,",") || strlen($list_users) > 0)
            {
                $newlist = $list_users.",".intval($add_uid);
            }
            else
            {
                $newlist = intval($add_uid);
            }
            $db->query("UPDATE users SET profile_visitor='".$db->escape_string($newlist)."' WHERE uid=".$to_uid);
        }

}
```

I want to add a User ID if its not present already in the field `profile_visitor`. For your notice, the `profile_visitor` list is comma separated list. Here are the variable's legend:

`$add_uid` = The user id that is going to be inserted in `profile_visitor` if its not present in already.
`$to_uid` = The User ID where `profile_visitor` column is present and the $add_uid add in if its not present.
`$visitors_list` = The comma separated list of profile visitors. Before adding any User ID that list will be empty (obviously)

The issue is: Each time the page loads (where that function is running) the list `profile_visitor` has the new User ID instead of adding the new User ID to the list.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
function add_profile_visitor($add_uid,$to_uid,$visitors_list)
{
    global $db;
        $list = trim($visitors_list);
        $list_users = explode(",",$list);

        if (in_array($add_uid,$list_users))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (strpos($list,",") || strlen($list) > 0)
            {
                $newlist = $list.",".intval($add_uid);
            }
            else
            {
                $newlist = intval($add_uid);
            }
            $db->query("UPDATE users SET profile_visitor='".$db->escape_string($newlist)."' WHERE uid=".$to_uid);
        }

}
```